# My ps3 isn't staying on

Tags: ps3

I've tried doing the things said on the same question, but it isn't working for me. I had tried keeping my finger on the power button until three beeps happened, but all it was beep once then did three really fast beeps, I don't know what to do. Help?

Comment: Welcome to the site! what do you mean by "on the same question?" is there another question you would like to link?

Comment: What I mean by that is, that there was a question that is very similar to mine. I didn't want to comment on it and mix up our answers with the similar question. They didn't have the yellow light like I did, but their ps3 wan't working as turning it on, same as me. Sorry for rambling, but thank you for the welcome.

Comment: If you can link the question you're talking about, it does help. If the questions are similar, we can link the two together, to help others find a solution faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is what people like to call the "Yellow Light Of Death" - similar to the PC's "Blue Screen of Death" or the Xbox's "Red Ring of Death". Basically, it means there is a hardware fault on your PS3's motherboard, causing it to fail to boot/operate properly, forcing an immediate power-down.

As the name suggests, the "YLoD" is usually accompanied by a flashing Yellow Light. If you don't see one, unplug the power cable for a short time (at least 30 seconds), plug it back in, and try again.

Alternatively, [repairs are possible](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/JamecoFavorites/PS3repair.html), but if you don't know what you're doing, this can lead to more problems than solutions.

Comment: Yellow does appear, and I have planned to repair the PS3 myself, the link you put does show me how to do it, since my own searches were futile of proper answers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AJCans if this answer solved your problem you should consider accepting it, you can do that by hitting the little Check mark under the voting numbers